# Comparing two environment properties files and have only the added properties in the new file migrated to the old file

Tags: linux, properties, configuration

Hello here is a setup of what im trying to accomplish

- The user has one environment properties file on their machine, it has a list of say 300 properties.
- We then deploy a new build to that same system with an updated version of that file with a few more properties added. I do not want to get rid of the old env prop file i just want to add those new properties without the user having to do it. example

File A (New Environment Properties file)

DB_CONNECTION=

DB_REPO=

DB_TEST=

DB_USER=

File B (Old environment properties)

DB_REPO=

DB_USER=

I just need the DB_CONNECTION and DB_TEST added to that file, there may be more to add this is just an example.

I have tried multiple grep and diff commands but they just output the screen or replace the whole file. I don't want to do this since the user has saved values so i just need the new properties added.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the following this will basically merge the old properties along with the values for each and add all the new properties. At the end of the script I just have the following command

```
sed -i 'property/d' environment.properties
```

Here is the merge script a co-worker helped me with

```
#!/bin/bash

old_file=
new_file=

while read new_line; do
        # Check to see if the current line is a comment.
        comment=$(echo "${new_line}" | grep '^[ \t]*[#!]')

    # Print comments as-is.
    if [ -n "${comment}" ]; then
            echo "${new_line}"
            continue
    fi

    # Get the property key.
    key=$(echo "${new_line}" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*\([^=:]\+\).*/\1/')

    # If the line isn't a comment or a property, skip it.
    if [ -z "${key}" ]; then
            echo "ERROR: invalid property: ${new_line}" 1>&2
            continue
    fi

    # Get the old value for the key.
    old_line=$(grep "^[ \t]*${key}[ \t]*[=:]" ${old_file})

    if [ -n "${old_line}" ]; then
            # If there is an old value, used it.
            echo "${old_line}" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
    else
            # Otherwise, use the new value.
            echo "${new_line}"
            echo "WARN: new property: ${key}" 1>&2
    fi
```

done < ${new_file}

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

I propose to source each file in its own subshell, execute `set` to show the complete set of environment variables, and compare both outputs.  Sounds complex but is typed rather easily:

```
diff <(source a.sh; set) <(source b.sh; set)
```

The output is a typical `diff` output, in my case:

```
19d18
< DB_CONNECTION=
21d19
< DB_TEST=
87c85
< _=a.sh
---
> _=b.sh
```

The last two lines (`_=a.sh` and `_=b.sh`) are not interesting; they just show the last used argument (which differs of course).

Now, to add the found stuff to the file you want to patch, you can use this:

```
diff  <(source a.sh; set) <(source b.sh; set) | grep '^<' | cut -c3- | grep -v '^_=' >> b.sh
```

This solution does not consider changed values, though.  If the user changed a value in his old config file, the new config file will have the standard value again, this will be a difference, so it will be added to the old config file.

You might not want this, so you might want to specify further requirements on how to handle changed values.